# FAU Removal and Storage

Tags: hvac, central-air, forced-air

I'm looking to move my FAU in a few months to the attic, but right now I need it moved out of my basement for a remodel. Can an FAU be stored in this manner for short term? Logic leads me to think so, but want to know:

- Risks?
- Storage best practices
- Things to look at for when removing an FAU

I'll ask a qualified tech as well, but want to bring this question up since I struggled to find answers online.

Comment: If anyone is concerned about my moving it due to needing to use HVAC, I live in San Diego and my last house I rented for four years I never used the unit.

Comment: What is a FAU, anyway?

Comment: You have qualified hvac techs here but I am not sure what a FAU is . I do have a universal 608 & 609 license. Are you talking about the air handler? Is this a heat pump? Or have a cooling coil? It makes a difference. If just has heat no problem.

Comment: From what I found it's a Forced Air Unit, basically an air handler.  Never heard the term before now!

Comment: Sorry! Lol. I'll update to say forced air unit. I felt dumb the first time I heard it, but they all use the term haha